# Looking for the right modules for user group management

Tags: 7, users

I am creating a site that works similarly to Groupon with D7, and I am having trouble finding the right modules to deliver the functionality.

I need to create different user groups: buyer and seller.

For the buyers I need to store their name, geo-location, and email address.

For sellers I need to store the name of their business, email, geo-location, and I want the sellers to be able to create a list of offers(nodes) linked to their business.

My initial thought is to find a module that enables custom field for user profile. I also need a separate registration & login page for each group, and assign new sign-ups to the appropriate group ( buyer vs seller) based on which page they use to register. What modules would you recommend in order to fulfill these requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need the Profile2 module. You can create a buyer and seller profile for each of your buyer and seller roles with different fields.

http://drupal.org/project/profile2

You might also find that the registration path module for Profile2 is helpful.

https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2_regpath

Comment: This should be the correct answer, profile2 sounds like exactly what OP is needing here. I voted up also but just wanted to reaffirm that by saying this is the answer I would have given just incase OP is wary of the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to manage this by using roles. 
Create two different roles: Buyer and Seller
As both roles have the same mandatory fields, it wont be an issue for you. Additionally, you can customise additional fields and rights for sellers.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know a way to create separate registration pages for the two groups and assign the new sign ups to the appreciate group based on what page they use to sign up?

Comment: You can create separate registration workflows using the Profile2 registration path module that I mention in my answer.